# In my app, power button control on android

Tags: android

My android devices 'power button'
sometimes use enable.

originally , when I clicked power button. immediately showing power menu.
but mostly not showing

I command in emulater

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

then showing

> I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version =0000
>
> N: Name="Android Power Button"
>
> P: Phys=
>
> S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input16
>
> U: Uniq=
>
> H: Handlers=kbd event13
>
> B: PROP=0
>
> B: EV=3
>
> B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I can check power button connected my device.

perhaps, Using this . power button control in my app?

surely, it should work power button

thanks.